# Checking an other value in a PHP setter function

Tags: php, class, oop

I have one classe named Media and two classes named Sms and Mail. 
Both extends the Media classe.

```
<?php

class Media {

protected $receiver;
protected $type;

    public function __construct($receiver, $type)
    {
      $this->setReceiver($receiver);
      $this->type($type);
    }

    public function getReceiver()
    {
      return $this->receiver;
    }

    public function setReceiver($receiver)
    {
      if($this->getType() == 'SMS' && !is_int($receiver)){
        //return exception if type is SMS and receiver not a number
      }

      $this->receiver = $receiver;
      return $this;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
      return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType($type)
    {
      $this->type = $type;
      return $this;
    }

}

class Sms extends Media {

}

$sms = new Sms('0123456789', 'SMS');
```

The result is this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Sms::type()

I can't access to `type`.

I would like to check if receiver is a number when the type is SMS in the setter method.

We can imagine an other classe of Mail which extends Media and i would like to verify if the receiver is a mail and not a number.

Where should I do this check?

Comment: You are just calling `$this->type` instead of `$this->setType` on your constructor..

Comment: Your `setReceiver($receiver)` method should be in the corresponding class - so in the SMS class, check it is a number, in the EMail class an address - etc.  The base class shouldn't know anything about what the derived classes want, it should let them handle this themselves.

Comment: @Tristan_CH did you see my answer?

Comment: @user2342558 Yes, i see it, thank you.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for your answer, I thought i was doing too much repetition but it's more clearer and each class manage its method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are trying to use a filed as method:

```
$this->type($type);
```

Instead, use its setter `setType`:

```
public function __construct($receiver, $type)
{
  $this->setType($type);
  $this->setReceiver($receiver);
}
```

Comment: Just to say that as in OP's code, `$this->setReceiver($receiver);` tests the type, which hasn't been set yet due to the call to `$this->setType($type);` is after it.  The 2 calls should be swapped round.